# Anonymous self-invoking JavaScript function - returning multiple objects

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

If I have original function (as an example):

```
var x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
var y = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
```

and I've gone ahead and made this into a self-invoking anonymous JS function, as such:

```
(function() {
    var x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
    var y = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
})()
```

am I doing something paradoxical? I'd like to access x and y as global variables, but the self-invoking anonymous function is useful in other areas that I'm not going into detail right now - I just want to keep it.

Should I be doing something like:

```
   var  x= (function() {
        var x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
        var y = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
        // Should I be doing something like
        return x
    })()
```

or

```
   var  x= (function() {
        var x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
        return x
    })()

   var  y = (function() {
        var x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
        return y
    })()
```

seems somewhat redundant?

Comment: In your second code-snippet I believe you will be creating a local instance of `x` and `y` and so will not be able to access these globally. Missing off `var` will create global variables. However I'm not sure why you would want to do this without seeing the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the goal of al this is, but maybe you could return both functions in an object, like so:

```
var funcs = (function() {
    var x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; };
    var y = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; };
    return {x: x, y: y};
})();

funcs.x();
funcs.y();
```

This is basically what the Module Pattern is about (see for example http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).

It's good! Depending on what you need, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
var x, y;
(function() {
  x = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
  y = function() { alert('tadaaa'); return 1; }
})();
```